# Callback method geocode items nominatim not work

Tags: openstreetmap, javascript, leaflet, geocoding, nominatim

```
function addr_search() {
    var inp = document.getElementById("addr");

    $.getJSON('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&limit=5&q=' + inp.value, function(data) {
        var items = [];

        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            bb = val.boundingbox;
            latitude = val.lat;
            longitude = val.lon;
            items.push("<li><a href='#' onclick='chooseAddr(" + latitude + ", " + longitude  + ", \"" + bb[0] + ", " + bb[2] + ", " + bb[1] + ", " + bb[3]  + ", \"" + val.osm_type + "\");return false;'>" + val.display_name + '</a></li>');
        });

        $('#results').empty();
        if (items.length != 0) {
            $('<p>', { html: "Search results:" }).appendTo('#results');
            $('<ul/>', {
                'class': 'my-new-list',
                html: items.join('')
            }).appendTo('#results');
        } else {
            $('<p>', { html: "O endereço não foi encontrado" }).appendTo('#results');
        }
    });
}
```

This method returns the geocode Nominatim. 
When clicked calls the method passing chooseAddr latitude, longitude, and limits the osm_type enreço clicked. 
But, I am not able to connect those returns.

If I do so it works:

```
   $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        latitude = val.lat;
        longitude = val.lon;
        items.push("<li><a href='#' onclick='chooseAddr(" + latitude + ", " + longitude  + ", \"" + val.osm_type + "\");return false;'>" + address.value + city.value + '</a></li>');
    });
```

But, I need to bring the bounds of the address to zoom using this attribute and it does not work:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    bb = val.boundingbox;
    latitude = val.lat;
    longitude = val.lon;
    items.push("<li><a href='#' onclick='chooseAddr(" + latitude + ", " + longitude  + ", \"" + bb[0] + ", " + bb[2] + ", " + bb[1] + ", " + bb[3]  + ", \"" + val.osm_type + "\");return false;'>" + val.display_name + '</a></li>');
});
```

I've tried various ways and I know it's something silly, but I could not seem to solve this.